# Keras: Shape Mismatch between Dense and Activation layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, reshape

Been trying to make a neural network in Keras, but ran into an issue where there is a shape mismatch between one of my dense layers and activation layers. Am I missing something obvious? Using Tensorflow backend.

```
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
(1509, 476, 4)
(1509,)
```

Then my model is as follows:

```
###Setup Keras to create a bidirectional convolutional recurrent NN based on DanQ NN
###See https://github.com/uci-cbcl/DanQ
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=320,
                 kernel_size=26,
                 padding="valid",
                 activation="relu",
                 strides=1, 
                 input_shape=(476, 4)
                ))

model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=13, strides=13))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(keras.layers.wrappers.Bidirectional(LSTM(320, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 320))))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(input_dim=34*640, units=925))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(input_dim=925, units=919))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

print('compiling model')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', class_mode="binary")

print('running at most 60 epochs')

model.fit(x_train, y_train.T, batch_size=100, epochs=60, shuffle=True, verbose=2, validation_split=0.1)

tresults = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)

print(tresults)

print(model.output_shape)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_48 to have shape (None, 919) but got array with shape (1509, 1)
```

The error seems to be originating from the input into the second activation layer using a sigmoid activation. e.g.:

```
model.add(Dense(input_dim=925, units=919))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Why would there be a mismatch?

Comment: you shouldn't have to have to specify input_dim and units in your dense layers. ex. last dense layer should be `model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))`

Comment: Thanks! That seems to solve the mismatch issue, but a new error pops up: `ValueError: Invalid argument "class_mode" passed to K.function with Tensorflow backend`, originating from `model.fit()`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: yeah you dont need to have the argument `class_mode='binary'` in `model.compile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in @djk47463's comment, your output is now has 919 values per sample, because that is the number of units in the last layer of your network. To correct this, either set your last layer's units to 1, or add a new final layer with an output dimension of 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=320,
             kernel_size=26,
             padding="valid",
             activation="relu",
             strides=1, 
             input_shape=(476, 4)
            ))
```

Try to add `input_dim = 4` on the place of `input_shape = (476,4)`.
May be it will work.

Comment: This is incorrect the docs state that if a convolution layer is the first layer in the network, an `input_shape` must be specified.  [docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/)

Comment: `input_dim` is from Keras 1.0. If I were to use that, I'd have to also specify `input_length = 476`, which is essentially the same as `input_shape = (476, 4)`.